# Using a select inside a while read is NOT giving me the result I want

Tags: bash

I have a file "in" that contains:

```
a
b
c
```

I run the following command:

```
cat in | while read el; do select yn in "yes" "no"; do echo $yn; done; done;
```

And get the following output:

```
1) yes
2) no
#?
#? 
#?
```

What I want is to be able to type 1 or 2 at each iteration.  What do I need to do differently to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're piping input into a while loop.  Within the loop, *stdin comes from the preceding command*, not from the console.  Your `select` statement is reading from the same pipe that the `read` statement is reading from.

Also, you don't need `cat`.

You need to preserve *stdin* for use in the select statement.  Try this:

```
while read el; do select yn in "yes" "no"; do echo $yn; break; 
done <&4; done 4<&0 < in
```

First, note that we're redirecting input using '<', rather than using `cat`.

This preserves your origin *stdin* (fd 0) in fd 4, and then inside the loop redirects input to `select` from fd 4.

Comment: Very cool, this definitely works.  

Is there a way to do it with a pipe?  The reason being is that my original input comes from a series of commands instead of a flat file.  I can definitely write the output to a file and redirect from the new file, but I'm curious how to do it with a pipe.

Comment: Yeah, you can do the same thing with a pipe.  In either case (using "<" or "|") you're just redirecting stdin.  Try this:  (cat input | while read el; do select yn in "yes" "no"; do echo $yn; break; 
done <&4; done) 4<&0

Answer (score -1):

`select` will read an input and execute it repeatedly until EOF; what you almost certainly want is the superficially similar:

```
cat in | while read el; do select yn in "yes" "no"; do echo $yn; break; done; done
```

Comment: It still doesn't prompt me for the select and only presents the prompt twice.  I'm still don't get the behavior I want.

Comment: Works For Me (TM)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I get all output at once and it doesn't wait for input. Similar to what the OP's version does, just sort of in a different order.